# Cannot set target directory when extracting an archive using tar

Tags: tar, aix

I'm trying to extract a tar archive to a specific directory. I've tried using -C flag but it doesn't work as expected. Here is the commandline I'm using

```
tar xvf myarchive.tar -C mydirectory/
```

This gives me a following error:

```
tar: file -C: not present in archive
tar: file mydirectory/: not present in archive
```

I've also tried setting the -C flag before the archive file but it just says this:

```
tar xvf -C mydirectory/ myarchive.tar
tar: -C: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
tar -tf shows that the tar archive does not have full path names:

```
tar -tf myarchive.tar
herareport/
herareport/bin/
...
```

Comment: Which OS are you running? `tar --version`?

Comment: IBM AIX. tar --version doesn't work

Comment: Please append the output of `tar -tf myarchive.tar` to your question.

Comment: I did what you asked but can you specify why? The archive is very big so I can't put the whole output here.

Comment: Out of curiosity what's wrong with `cd /new/directory ; tar xf /path/to/archive` ?

Comment: @voretaq7: he's asking why the `-C` option doesn't work (on AIX)?

Comment: @quanta `I'm trying to extract a tar archive to a specific directory.` <- doesn't require the (apparently broken?) `-C` option - unless you're right and somehow the archive was created with full paths (leading `/` preserved), but his `-t` output doesn't show a leading `/`

Comment: Well basically what I'm doing is I have sudo rights to user "myuser". I want to create a command that will take a tar-file in my home directory and extract it to the home directory of myuser.

How would I do that without the -C option?

Comment: If I try to use `sudo -u myuser cd /home/myuser/ ; sudo -u myuser tar xvf /path/to/myarchive.tar` it still tries to extract to the wrong directory.

Comment: @palto See my answer below (and if it works incorporate your previous comment into the question :-)

Comment: As of September 2015, tar xf -C still doesn't work on AIX 6. I had to make a shell script which changes to the target directory, then does something like gunzip < filename.tgz | tar xf -. Since I run via single-command ssh it's okay to abandon myself in the new directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

::dusts off `Crusty Old Unix Monger` badge::

From the comments:

> If I try to use `sudo -u myuser cd /home/myuser/; sudo -u myuser tar xvf /path/to/myarchive.tar` it tries to extract to the wrong directory.

That's because `sudo cd` is not persistent (Try it yourself -- `sudo cd /` and then run `pwd` -- you'll be in the directory you started in, so your second `sudo` command isn't running where you want it).

To fix this you need to tell `sudo` to start a shell of its own so you can run multiple commands as the target user.
`sudo -u myuser -s -- "(cd /home/myuser ; tar xvf /path/to/tarfile)"` will probably do the trick.

(If for some reson your version of `sudo` dislikes this, `sudo -u myuser sh -c "cd /home/myuser ; tar xvf /path/to/tarfile"` should also work.)

(Of course none of this explains why `-C` isn't working as expected on AIX, but it should solve your immediate problem)

Comment: Technically you don't need my parentheses () above - I type them out of habit from years of `tar cf - . | (cd /somewhere ; tar xvf -)` directory cloning...

Comment: Thanks for helping me but it still doesn't work :) I tried `sudo -u myuser -s -- "(cd /tmp/ ; pwd)"` but it says `/usr/bin/bash: (cd /tmp/ ;  pwd): No such file or directory`

Comment: Removing the parentheses just gives me the same error.. but without parentheses.

Comment: @palto Hmm... alternative added (invoke the shell manually with `-c` to specify the commands to run).

Comment: That -c did the trick, thanks. I'm marking this as the right answer. The -C option on the tar is broken on the AIX-machine so there might not be anything else that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tar -xvC mydirectory/ -f myarchive.tgz
```

Comment: `tar -xvC mydirectory/ -f myarchive.tar`
`tar: /dev/rmt0: No such file or directory`

Comment: Well I can't seem to get the formatting right on these comments but I hope you get the picture what happens

Comment: Yeah, I just tested this on some old RS/6000 running in some dusty corner of our local DC and got the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Since your tarball was created with full path, download the [GNU tar](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/altlic.html) and try again to see if it works.

Comment: Can I use that without root privileges? I'm not actually a super user on this server :)

Answer (score 0):

`mv myarchive.tgz mydirectory/ && tar xvf mydirectory/myarchive.tgz`

Comment: That still extracts to the parent directory, not mydirectory

Answer (score 0):

Extracts *myarchive.tar* to */mydirectory*

**Commands:**

```
cd /mydirectory
pax -rv -f myarchive.tar -s ',^/,,'
```